# How to prevent Finder windows from automatically popping up when I attach a disk?

Tags: macos, finder, external-disk, firewire

I have a removable Firewire drive.  It has several partitions, many of which have Mac OS installers on them (I'm a developer/sysadmin, and need to reinstall fairly frequently).  However, I also use this disk for backup and storage, so I don't want to install an operating system *every* time I attach it.

Whenever I attach the drive, Finder pops up a couple windows automatically, offering to install the operating system.  I'd prefer that Finder not pop up these windows.

Why do only some of the partitions pop up windows?  How can I disable it altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder to open is controlled in a special field in the filesystem header. You can change this entry using the `bless` command as described [in this source](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009121606541533).

To review the current settings, use the following command:

```
bless --info /Volumes/Any Disk/
```

You can change which folder of the mounted volume is opened in Finder on mount:

```
sudo bless --folder "/Volumes/Any Disk/" --openfolder "/Volumes/Any Disk/Documentation"
```

You can reset the information completely as well:

```
sudo bless --unbless /Volumes/Any Disk/
```

Note that using these `bless` commands make the volume unbootable, so be careful if you need this. Of course, they also do not work for volumes with a read-only filesystem/medium, such as a CD/DVD.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is set in the HFS+ filesystem header. I found some technical detail [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/16194-making-mounted-dmgs-pop-up.html), including C source to modify it.

> The idea is to set word 2 of the finder info field in the HFS+ volume
>   header. The Mac OS 9/X Finders know to open a window corresponding to
>   the dirID stored in this field.

And there's an ancient app to set it [here](http://autoopen.nibfile.com/).

For a tool to read the volume header check out fileXray (non free.) Its [manual](http://filexray.com/fileXray.pdf) shows the location of the relevant flag on page 170, it looks like :

```
# Open folder ID
         finderInfo[2] = 0
```

If you're also using these disks for backups you probably aren't going to want to mess with the filesystem header, certainly not with the outdated tools above.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent a volume from opening in finder when mounted run the bless command like so:

```
sudo bless -folder "/Volumes/volumename"/
```