# Prevent Sierra from opening a Window for a new Volume

Tags: finder, macos, usb, disk-volume

I have a mobile LTE modem that I connect to via Wifi. Whenever I connect via USB (for charging) Sierra opens a `/Volumes/Web Connection` Finder window. How can I prevent that?

I can't use [bless](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19183/how-to-prevent-finder-windows-from-automatically-popping-up-when-i-attach-a-disk) as the volume is read-only.

I also tried setting

```
defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages auto-open-ro-root -bool false
defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages auto-open-rw-root -bool false
defaults write com.apple.finder OpenWindowForNewRemovableDisk -bool false
```

but they had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't relied on this in the Sierra times, but you might get lucky with the venerable unix fstab functionality and removing your default commands that weren't effective:

```
diskutil info /Volumes/Web\ Connection
```

Get the UUID and add a line to your `/etc/fstab` file

```
UUID=12345678-1ABC-1CDE-1FGH-123456789012 none hfs rw,noauto
```

There are some more details at https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7942 covering a nice use of the `vifs` command which safely edits the `/etc/fstab` file in place. Some good discussion on the mounting mechanics are at: [How does Mac OS X decide which volumes to mount? One of my disks doesn't mount at boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36021/how-does-mac-os-x-decide-which-volumes-to-mount-one-of-my-disks-doesnt-mount-a)